# How to properly downgrade mysql 8 to 5.7 in centos 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0, downgrade

I would like to downgrade MySQL 8 to MySQL 5.7 on centos 8, can I get the proper steps/commands. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781788395809/1/ch01lvl1sec18/downgrading-from-mysql-8-0

Comment: There is no downgrade procedure. Backup your databases, deinstall version 8, install version 5.7, restore databases. Alternatively you may stop version 8 and install version 5.7 using another directories (strict interfere absence!). Then you may either start both servers while set one of them to another ports, or start only one of them at a time (stop one then start another).

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade from MySQL 8.0 to MySQL 5.7, or from a MySQL 8.0 release to a previous MySQL 8.0 release, is not supported. The only supported alternative is to restore a backup taken before upgrading. It is therefore imperative that you back up your data before starting the upgrade process.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/downgrading.html